# Office Fabric UI React - HoverCard width

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I use HoverCard Office Fabric UI React component to show preview of images, although I can configure height of the card I don't see similar properties for width. What is a possible solution to set width? I saw property `styles?: IHoverCardStyles` but don't understand how to use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HoverCard.styles` allows to specify style for the *host element* but what you are after `HoverCard.expandingCardProps` property.

One option to specify `HoverCard` custom width would be to override style via [`IExpandingCardProps.styles`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/HoverCard/ExpandingCard.types.ts)  like this:

```
public render() {

    const rootStyle = { width: "800px" }; //set custom width 

    const expandingCardProps: IExpandingCardProps = {
        onRenderCompactCard: this.renderCompactCard,
        onRenderExpandedCard: this.renderExpandedCard,
        renderData: itemDetails,
        styles: {"root": rootStyle}
    };



    return (
        <div>
            <HoverCard expandingCardProps={expandingCardProps} instantOpenOnClick={true}>
                <div>{itemDetails.title}</div>
            </HoverCard>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/x9qo0jxjnw) for your reference